# install.packages fails to find installed package dependencies

Tags: r

I am experiencing an issue where `install.packages` pulls down the package I want but then fails to complete the installation. The reason given is that some dependency package is not available. Except that those packages are available.

For example:

```
options(repos="http://cran.r-project.org")
install.packages("viridis")
# Installing package into ‘/devel/r-user-packages/bamboo-CI/base’
# (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
# trying URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/viridis_0.5.0.tar.gz'
# Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1754678 bytes (1.7 MB)
# ==================================================
# downloaded 1.7 MB
# 
# * installing *source* package ‘viridis’ ...
# ** package ‘viridis’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
# ** R
# ** inst
# ** preparing package for lazy loading
# ** help
# *** installing help indices
#   converting help for package ‘viridis’
#     finding HTML links ... done
#     reexports                               html
# Rd warning: /tmp/Rtmpm2qFw0/R.INSTALL66597c318399/viridis/man/reexports.Rd:22: missing file link ‘inferno’
# ... more stuff similar to ^^
# *** copying figures
# ** building package indices
# ** installing vignettes
# ** testing if installed package can be loaded
# Error : package ‘viridisLite’ required by ‘viridis’ could not be found
# Error: loading failed
# Execution halted
# ERROR: loading failed
# * removing ‘/devel/r-user-packages/bamboo-CI/base/viridis’
# 
# The downloaded source packages are in
#         ‘/tmp/RtmpUSId98/downloaded_packages’
# Warning message:
# In install.packages("viridis") :
#   installation of package ‘viridis’ had non-zero exit status
```

This is clear enough except that `viridisLite` is installed and loads without issue. Immediately after getting the above errors I did:

```
library(viridisLite)
plasma(4)
# [1] "#0D0887FF" "#9C179EFF" "#ED7953FF" "#F0F921FF"
```

I don't think this is an issue particular to `viridis`. I've gotten very similar errors where `devtools` fails to find an installed copy of `withr`, where `doParallel` fails to find an installed copy of `foreach`, etc.

I've tried running against 3 different CRAN mirrors without any luck. I started with a completely clean (except base packages) library path. I also double checked to make sure installed dependencies (`viridisLite`, `withr`, and `foreach` in my examples above) were versions acceptable to the packages I'm trying to install.

I'm running R v3.4.3 on a CentOS 7 machine. Most packages install fine (I updated about 200 packages, with 15 failures).

Are there any known issues around this? Why can't R find these packages? I suspect something else is going wrong, but that it is triggering an unhelpful message. However I have no idea what the real issue might be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using https. `options(repos="https://cran.r-project.org")`

Comment: Thanks very much. That seems to have done the trick. Any idea why the http version was causing the issues I observed above?

Comment: I think they shut down the http sites to improve security.